# How to execute a method on a struct for each instance in a collection of structs until an error is encountered in Rust?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

I am trying to run the `execute` method for each instance of the struct `LogCommand` that I have in a collection of structs, stopping when an error is encountered.

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

use anyhow::Error;
use futures::future::ok;
use futures::stream::{TryStream, TryStreamExt};

pub struct LogCommand {
    message: String,
}

impl LogCommand {
    fn new(message: String) -> LogCommand {
        LogCommand { message }
    }

    fn execute(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<bool, Error>>>> {
        println!("{}", self.message);
        Box::pin(ok(true))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut structs: Vec<LogCommand> = Vec::new();
    structs.push(LogCommand::new("Test1".to_string()));
    structs.push(LogCommand::new("Test2".to_string()));
    structs.push(LogCommand::new("Test3".to_string()));

    run_all_methods(structs);
}

async fn run_all_methods(logCommands: Vec<LogCommand>) -> Result<bool, Error> {
    futures::stream::iter(logCommands).try_for_each(|i| i.execute())
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
the method `try_for_each` exists for struct `Iter<IntoIter<LogCommand>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<LogCommand>>: TryStream`
which is required by `futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<LogCommand>>: TryStreamExt`
`&futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<LogCommand>>: TryStream`
which is required by `&futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<LogCommand>>: TryStreamExt`
`&mut futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<LogCommand>>: TryStream`
which is required by `&mut futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<LogCommand>>: TryStreamExt`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
iter.rs(9, 1): doesn't satisfy `_: TryStreamExt`
iter.rs(9, 1): doesn't satisfy `_: TryStream`
```

Any idea on how I might go about running each of these methods and stopping when an error is encountered, without directly using a for loop? (I have been asked to write this in a more functional manner.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `try_for_each()` is a method for `TryStream`s — *streams of* `Result`s — but `futures::stream::iter(logCommands)` is not a stream of `Result`s but of `LogCommand`s. The `Result`s haven't appeared yet because `execute()` hasn't been done yet.

To get the stream of `Result`s, you can use [`StreamExt::then()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.then), and then to get the completion or error you can use one of the `TryStream` operations.

But you haven't said what you want to do with the `bool`s. If you don't actually want any data there, you can replace it with `()` and collect:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;

...

impl LogCommand {
    fn new(message: String) -> LogCommand {
        LogCommand { message }
    }

    fn execute(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), Error>>>> {
        println!("{}", self.message);
        Box::pin(ok(()))
    }
}

async fn run_all_methods(log_commands: Vec<LogCommand>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    futures::stream::iter(log_commands)
        .then(|i| i.execute())
        .try_collect()
        .await
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b4d0f677289e8509b614d2e6c426e9c)

If you want to combine the `bool`s in some way (logical AND or OR), then maybe [`try_fold()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/prelude/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_fold) will suit. If you want to exit early if the bool has a particular value, convert it to an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can read why your code doesn't work as is in [Kevin Reids answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76863269/442760). But since I had already written the code when I saw that I'll add my approach for `run_all_methods` as well:

```rust
async fn run_all_methods(logCommands: Vec<LogCommand>) -> Result<bool, Error> {
    logCommands
        .iter()
        .map(|c| c.execute())
        .collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>()
        .try_fold(false, |acc, b| ok(acc || b))
        .await
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7cec7d4ca05cacea42571ad7a475b994)

Instead of immediately creating a `Stream` I went for the option of staying in `Iterator` land as long as possible, since they're used quite more frequently than streams I believe that route is more likely to be optimized for in the compiler and you get all the bells and whistles that are implemented for them (granted most are replicated in `Stream`s but that API doesn't feel quite as polished & complete)

After mapping the structs to `Futures` I collect into a `FuturesUnordered` though depending on the needs it might as well have been a `FuturesOrdered` giving me a little more clontrol over how values are produced from the `Stream` than the `stream::iter` gives.

Since you haven't specified what you want to do with all the bools I've opted for a disjunction of them. For a collection you'd replace the `try_fold` with `try_collect` and switch `bool` with `Vec<bool>` in the return type, for an early return you'd return an `Err` variant instead of `Ok` in the fold.

Comment: Don't both `FuturesUnordered` and `FuturesOrdered` execute all futures in parallel? Part of why we're evaluating `stream::iter` is to ensure they're executed serially, and only executed if the previous result was `Ok`.

Comment: If that's a concern then yes you shouldn't use `Futures*` they do indeed execute the futures concurrently.